# How to replace all character with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this: `How to replace all character with Regex`

I would like each character to be wrapped by its own  tag set, as in:

```
<span>H</span><span>o</span><span>w</span><span> </span><span>t</span><span>o</span><span> </span><span>r</span><span>e</span><span>p</span><span>l</span><span>a</span><span>c</span><span>e</span><span> </span><span>a</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span> </span><span>c</span><span>h</span><span>a</span><span>r</span><span>a</span><span>c</span><span>t</span><span>e</span><span>r</span><span> </span><span>w</span><span>i</span><span>t</span><span>h</span><span> </span><span>R</span><span>e</span><span>g</span><span>e</span><span>x</span>
```

How can I do this using regular expressions and Javascript?
Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to wrap each character in a `<span>`?

Comment: I see no difference between both texts

Comment: Does anyone see any diff between input and output ? o0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
"this is a string".replace(/(.)/g, "<span>$1</span>")
```

will output this:

```
<span>t</span><span>h</span><span>i</span><span>s</span><span> </span><span>i</span><span>s</span><span> </span><span>a</span><span> </span><span>s</span><span>t</span><span>r</span><span>i</span><span>n</span><span>g</span>
```

Comment: True, if by "will output" you mean "will return" or "will evaluate to". :-)

Comment: You actually don't need a group here, just `/./g` and `$&`. Also, this won't replace newlines (no idea if this is desired).

Comment: Yeah, yeah, yeah. I tested in Chrome's console which outputs what ever is returned. My brain filled in the rest. I'm leaving it.

Answer (score 1):

Though not using regex, you might also look into this plugin [lettering.js](http://www.ajaxshake.com/plugin/EN/525/9b916db8/style-individual-letters-with-javascript-lettering-js.html). It provides a simplified way to split up strings individually, as you're doing manually. From the website, it provides this example:

```
<h1 class="fancy_title">
  <span class="char1">S</span>
  <span class="char2">o</span>
  <span class="char3">m</span>
  <span class="char4">e</span>
  <span class="char5"></span>
  <span class="char6">T</span>
  <span class="char7">i</span>
  <span class="char8">t</span>
  <span class="char9">l</span>
  <span class="char10">e</span>
</h1>
```

The result is comparable and has even additional functionality you might care for.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what language you are using.
Anyway, search regex is "`(.)`", i.e. a group with any character.
The replace string should be "`<span>\1</span>`".

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:JavaScript].